# html5 date: how to get date as yyyy-mm-ddTH:i:s+Z format in javascript

Tags: html, angularjs, date

I am trying to get the date using html5 `date` type,and it is used for an api call with some parameters,but i will get the following error message from api.

> date field must be yyyy-mm-ddTH:i:s+Z

I wll read the date as this format

```
Sun Jun 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

So how can i convert the above date into  `yyyy-mm-ddTH:i:s+Z` format?

Note:
I am using javascript

**UPDATE**

I am used `toISOString()` method but it didn't worked

Comment: I'd recommend [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for any date manipulaton/formating

Comment: @AlonEitan there is no solution without momentjs

Comment: since you are using angularjs just add `<input type="date">` check this link for more information https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[date]

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)...

Please, check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5awjbk9c/)

```js
var time = 'Sun Jun 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530';

time = moment(time).format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ");

$('.time').text(time);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you wanted:

```js
function getTimeZone(date) {
  var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset(),
    o = Math.abs(offset);
  return (offset < 0 ? "+" : "-") + ("00" + Math.floor(o / 60)).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + (o % 60)).slice(-2);
}

function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  var sec = date.getSeconds();
  var timeZone = getTimeZone(date);

  return year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + mins + ':' + sec + ' ' + timeZone;

}


document.write(getFormattedDate(new Date()));
```

This will print: 2016-5-2 19:54:59 +06:00

JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sktajbir/pmbdk33L/2/

FYI, getTimeZone() function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript).

Thanks.